# cannot apply index on expresstion system.collections.generic.linkedlist<T>

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have made a class :

```
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public List<Node> Successor { get; set; }

}
```

and in some method i want to do the following

```
partice.path= new  LinkedList<Node>();
```

but i cant reach the ".elementat()" method and other extensions.

ps: all the classes above are in   silverlight class library,i don't know if it is relevant to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you're using the framework classes (as suggested in the title) or your own class, given your `Node` declaration...

If you're using the framework classes, make sure to include:

```
using System.Linq;
```

At the top of your file.  Also, make sure to include a reference to `System.Core.dll` in your project.

If you're using your own class, and you want to use the [Enumerable.ElementAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233.aspx) extension method, you need to make your class implement `IEnumerable<T>`.

That being said, you might want to just use the framework's [`LinkedList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx) class instead of rolling your own...